# Telerik BarIndicator cuts off edges

Tags: telerik

I am using a RadRadicalGuage from Telerik with an outside bar indicator.  When I set the indicator to go full scale it cuts off the top and side of the bar indicator.  Not sure how to fix this.

```
    <telerik:RadRadialGauge x:Name="DrillPressureGauge"  telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Height="225" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="225" Margin="198,44,0,0" >
        <telerik:RadialScale Min ="0" Max="10000" Foreground="Transparent">
            <telerik:RadialScale.Ranges>
                <telerik:GaugeRange Min="0"
                                Max="6000"
                                StartWidth="0.20"
                                EndWidth="0.20"
                                Background="Green"
                                IndicatorBackground="Green" />
                <telerik:GaugeRange Min="6000"
                                Max="7750"
                                StartWidth="0.20"
                                EndWidth="0.20"
                                Background="Orange"
                                IndicatorBackground="Orange" />
                <telerik:GaugeRange Min="7750"
                                Max="10000"
                                StartWidth="0.20"
                                EndWidth="0.20"
                                Background="Red"
                                IndicatorBackground="Red" />
            </telerik:RadialScale.Ranges>
            <telerik:RadialScale.Indicators>
                <telerik:BarIndicator
                        Value="10000"
                        StartWidth="0.1"
                        EndWidth="0.1"
                        EmptyFill="Transparent"
                        Background="LightGray"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        telerik:ScaleObject.Location="Outside"/>
                <telerik:Needle />
                <telerik:Pinpoint/>
            </telerik:RadialScale.Indicators>
            <telerik:RadialScale.CustomItems>
                <TextBlock Text="12345"
                   telerik:ScaleObject.RelativeX="0.35"
                   telerik:ScaleObject.RelativeY="0.85" Background="White" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="36.063" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </telerik:RadialScale.CustomItems>
        </telerik:RadialScale>
    </telerik:RadRadialGauge>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by adding a radius value of 0.9 to the RadialScale.